# Mauch Loop Testing Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
investment = 10000
for i in range(20):
    yearly_interest = investment *.05
    investment = investment * yearly_interest
investment = round(investment, 2)
```

Hi I'm not quite sure how this loops gives the answer desired. If someone could help me out in understanding why it didn't raise the answer and what could be done with it. In the Mauch book they explain it's one of the loops, but it's not returning the desired value ("What will be the value after 20 years")

Comment: Shouldn't it be `investment = investment + yearly_interest`?  As is, this pretty quickly explodes past the maximum value of a `float`.

Comment: you're right that should be a + , now that i've fixed that plus the previous print has changed. it was showing INF in lowercase. now it shows nothing. am i supposed to put a print() somewhere?? ...... OKAY you helped me fix it, its working haha. Thank you very much.

Comment: investment = investment + yearly_interest ; that explained what i was looking for with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `yearly_interest`should be added to `investment` instead of multiplying `investment` by it.

```
investment = 10000
for i in range(20):
    yearly_interest = investment *.05
    investment = investment + yearly_interest
investment = round(investment, 2)
```